# How to apply filter on GraphQL running on JSON file?

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to run a GraphQL query on JSON file. It is working well, but when I try to add a filter in it, it still shows all the records.

[My JSON data file](https://jsonblob.com/e53472fc-8b43-11e9-a28e-f1f76faa2bd9)

[My JSON Schema](https://jsonblob.com/45b5fe0a-8b45-11e9-a28e-691c10f872ed)

GraphQL:

```
{
  allDataJson(filter: {content: {elemMatch: {activityMeta: {contentType: {eq: "iframe-game"}}}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        content {
          name
          type
          link
          description
          content {
            score
            gameOverTitle
            gameOverProgress
          }
          activityMeta {
            contentLink
            contentType
            inScene
            backgroundImages {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

JSON data config:

[image]

GraphQL Query Results:

[image]

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your query only returns a single node and filters are only for filtering nodes (and not the data within nodes).

It looks like you trying to query only `content` that has `activityMeta.contentType === "iframe-game"`.

Are you able to split your json up into seperate files? If yes, then you can actually create different node types with `gatsby-transformer-json`.

Assuming a folder structure of:

```
src/
  data/
    category.json
    content.json
    contentGroup.json
    menu.json
```

you can create a different node type for each file like this:

```
    plugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-transformer-json`,
          options: {
            typeName: ({ node }) => {
              return node.relativePath.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
            }
          }
        },
        ...
    ]
```

and this will allow you to make separate queries such as `allCategory`, `allContent`, `allContentGropup`, `allMenu`.

Once you are at this point, you easily filter the `allContent` query to only match nodes if `node.activityMeta.contentType === "iframe-game"` with the following query

```
    query MyQuery {
      allContent(filter: {activityMeta: {contentType: {eq: "iframe-game"}}}) {
        nodes {
          name
          activityMeta {
            contentType
            contentLink
            inScene
            backgroundImages {
              path
            }
          }
          type
          link
          description
          content {
            score
            gameOverTitle
            gameOverProgress
          }
        }
      }
    }
```